# zend and smarty site clone problem

Tags: php, zend-framework, smarty

I created a site a while ago using zend and smarty. The site is hosted on a virtual machine with centOS. Now I want to create a similar site so I creeated another virtual host, ftp user etc etc on the same machine.

I modified the ini file that contained the paths:
paths.base      = /var/www/html/new_path
paths.data      = /var/www/html/new_path/data 
paths.templates = /var/www/html/new_path/templates 
paths.cache     = /var/www/html/new_path/data/tmp/cache 
paths.public    = /var/www/html/new_path/public_html

The porblem is that somehow when I try to access zend/loader.php (I try to load a database object) it is used the loader from the old path (/var/www/html/oldpath/include/zend/loader.php) so naturally I cant access any new objects I create for the new site 
(
Warning: include_once(DatabaseObject/New.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/**old_path**/include/Zend/Loader.php on line 146

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'DatabaseObject/New.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/var/www/html/**old_path**/include:/usr/share/pear/') in /var/www/html/**old_path**/include/Zend/Loader.php on line 146

Fatal error: Class 'DatabaseObject_Chat' not found in /var/www/html/**new_path**/include/Controllers/ChatController.php on line 8
).

There are no other paths defined anywhere.
Caching is disabled.
It occurs on different computers, browsers, etc so is not a local problem (residual value of some-type).

For any details just ask... I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zend_Loader looks into include directories defined in your public/index.php. The [include path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) must be set properly to contain both the old directories and the new ones. Note the respective order specified by your include path.

The code in public/index.php should look similar to the following, assuming the use of ZF1:

```
<?php
...
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../../project_name/path_for_inclusion'),
    get_include_path(),
))); 
...
```

The include path can be also adjusted in your .htaccess:

```
php_value include_path "/var/www/path:/var/www/second_path:/var/www/third"
```

or you can achieve the effect in general without ZF-specific code:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path_to_add);
```